# Can we embed multiple videos in HTML?

Tags: html, video, embed, avi

Can we embed multiple video files in html? 
If I want to play multiple files in sequence what would be the coding for that?
How can I embed .avi files? I know how to embed .flv files.

Answer (score 0):

Embed player like:

```
<OBJECT id="VIDEO" width="320" height="240" style="position:absolute; left:0;top:0;" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" type="application/x-oleobject">
<PARAM NAME="URL" VALUE="your file or url">
<PARAM NAME="SendPlayStateChangeEvents" VALUE="True">
<PARAM NAME="AutoStart" VALUE="True">
<PARAM name="uiMode" value="none">
<PARAM name="PlayCount" value="9999"></OBJECT>
```

make play list using  asx file. for example asx file:

```
<ASX Version = "3.0">
<TITLE>Vocal's Midi Message Board</TITLE>
<ENTRY><TITLE>Title of Video 1</TITLE>
<REF HREF="http://yourvideo.com/video1.wmv" />
</ENTRY>
<ENTRY>    <TITLE>Title of Video 2</TITLE>
<REF HREF="http://yourvideoURL.com/video2.wmv" />
</ENTRY></ASX>
```